Sort wordpress post based on highest views
Here's is my post which shows only those posts who has views. Views are counted using wp-view-counter plugin and show those posts as well who are categorized as trending term either they have views or not. Now the only thing which I want to achieve is to display posts by highest views to lowest views.
function my_custom_elementor_query( $query ) {
    // Check if it's the Elementor post query with a specific query ID
        global $wpdb;

        // Construct the SQL query
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->posts}.ID FROM {$wpdb->posts}";

        // Add JOIN clauses for meta and taxonomy tables
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id)";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON ({$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id)";
        $sql .= " LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} ON ({$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id)";

        // Add WHERE conditions
        $sql .= " WHERE 1=1";
        $sql .= " AND ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'entry_views' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value != '')";
        $sql .= " OR ({$wpdb->terms}.slug = 'trending' AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'filter')";
        $sql .= " OR ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'entry_views' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value != '' AND {$wpdb->terms}.slug != 'trending')";

        // Execute the query
        $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );

        // Set post__in parameter to fetch only these posts
        $query->set( 'post__in', $post_ids );
    }
add_action( 'elementor/query/custom_filter', 'my_custom_elementor_query' );


function my_custom_elementor_query( $query ) {
    // Check if it's the Elementor post query with a specific query ID
    global $wpdb;

    // Construct the SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT {$wpdb->posts}.ID, CAST({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AS UNSIGNED) AS views
            FROM {$wpdb->posts}
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id)
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} ON ({$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->term_relationships}.object_id)
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} ON ({$wpdb->term_relationships}.term_taxonomy_id = {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_taxonomy_id)
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} ON ({$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.term_id = {$wpdb->terms}.term_id)
            WHERE ({$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = 'entry_views' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value != '')
            OR ({$wpdb->terms}.slug = 'trending' AND {$wpdb->term_taxonomy}.taxonomy = 'filter')
            GROUP BY {$wpdb->posts}.ID
            ORDER BY views DESC";

    // Execute the query
    $post_ids = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );

    // Set post__in parameter to fetch only these posts
    if ( ! empty( $post_ids ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post__in', $post_ids );
        // Ensure the query respects the order of IDs
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
    }
}
add_action( 'elementor/query/custom_filter', 'my_custom_elementor_query' );

Pay attention to these 4 things:

Casting meta_value as an integer: To ensure the views are
properly ordered numerically, the meta_value from postmeta is cast
to UNSIGNED.
Ordering by views: The ORDER BY views DESC ensures
posts are sorted from highest to lowest views.
Setting orderby to
post__in: This maintains the order of posts as retrieved by the SQL
query.
Grouping by post ID: To handle potential duplicates
correctly.


Policy: Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned
